# How the CSS content attribute works?

Tags: css

Can some one explain how the `content` attribute internally work in the browser. Does it create a new node in the DOM even it is not displayed in the webInspector. And will it have the same influences of memory consumption like a real DOM node?

Answer (score 2):

From the **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content)**:

> This property (content) is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements to
>   generate content in a document. **Generated content does not alter the
>   document tree. In particular, it is not fed back to the document
>   language processor (e.g., for reparsing).**

Also, according to **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content)**:

> Objects inserted using the content property are anonymous replaced
>   elements. In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose
>   representation is outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external
>   objects whose representation is independant of the CSS. Typical
>   replaced elements are `<image>`, `<object>`, `<video>` or forms element like
>   `<textarea>`, `<input>`. Some elements, like `<audio>` or `<canvas>` are
>   replaced elements only in specific cases. Object inserted using the
>   CSS content properties are anonymous replaced elements. CSS handled replaced elements specifically in some cases, like when calculating margins and some auto values.
>   Note that some replaced elements, but not all, have intrinsic
>   dimensions or a defined baseline, which is used by some CSS properties
>   like vertical-align.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content)

> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it
>   is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for
>   reparsing).